# How to delete a document in documentdb using c# where i have variable with timestamp by quering it

Tags: azure

I have a  document in with data like following format.

```
[
   {
    "TimeStamp": "3/18/2015 7:57:21 PM",
   }
]
```

I need to query this document only with date(3/18/2015) and delete that document using c#. Time in the TimeStamp (7:57:21 PM) should not be queried. How can I do it?
If there are multiple records with the same date, i need to delete all those documents.

Thanks
Naveen

Comment: Put the example timestamp into a code formatted block

Answer (score 1):

Today you need to know the doc._self to delete a Document.
So do a query for the document(s) based on any criteria you like, including the timestamp (no reason to not use this, it's there for that reason). Then execute a delete statement against each document found.

If you want to do this in a batch to minimize server roundtrips, consider doing this in a stored procedure, similar to our published BulkImport.js script.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Can I have the delete statement for this.that will be fine for me. Actually i need to sort the documents with time stamp per day and hour and then delete that document.

Comment: call the DeleteDocumentAsync method of the SDK, or do a DELETE directly on the REST API. There is no DELETE in SQL grammar, yet